# Capturing Windows 7 with DISM or ImageX

Tags: windows-7, deployment, waik

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format#DISM)

> Before Window Server 2012 and Windows 8, DISM had incorporated the
>   majority of ImageX functions but not all; ImageX was still needed for
>   image capture.However, DISM deprecated ImageX in Windows 8.

Does this mean if I use a recent version of DISM (like from [WADK for windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx)) I can use it to capture an image in Windows 7? Working on win 7 x64 system, trying to make a generalized image.

Comment: Try it, see what happens... I would say it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact, current versions of the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) now use DISM instead of ImageX when capturing images.

Side note: You should look into MDT if you're building a "generalized image" for multiple machines, e.g., in a corporate environment.

Comment: I'm having trouble differentiating between WADK and MDT tools for this purpose

Comment: The ADK is really doing the bulk of the work. MDT relies on ADK for functionality. You can sort of think as MDT as a GUI for the ADK. That's overly simplistic, but gives you a feel for the relationship.

Comment: It is my understanding they both come with `dism.exe`. Or does the MDT installer include WADK. It seems they have separte setups.

Comment: *separate*. I'll do some testing soon with the old Win7 default dism(6.1) and the new one. Let you know what I find.

Comment: Works with the `Windows 10 ADK` on windows 7 enterprise x64. I captured with WinPE, note I had to copy the *entire* DISM (only 9MB) folder to WinPE for it to work. Only copying `dism.exe` gave some missing dll related error.